# Close a chat room

Tags: support, chat

I opened this chat room

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/45401/question-to-sorade-from-deltaiv

but it was on the wrong site (I should have opened it in Cross-Validation). How can I close it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rooms will close themselves eventually:

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.
>
> Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted. Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen. Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface.

[Source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#retention)

So just wait and it will close itself

Comment: User could put the room into gallery mode, if they have the privilege (1K), to prevent anyone stumbling in and start leaving messages.

Comment: it should be already a gallery chat. I created it as such, and there's the small lock simbol next to the name. Hovering over it shows a popup saying that it's gallery.